# Is it possible to flow HTML elements up using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .part { background-color: blue; width: 40%; float: right; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="part">Hello World 1 </div>
            <div class="part">Hello World 2</div>
            <div class="part">Hello World 3</div>
            <div class="part">Hello World 4</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Right now the text is flowing to the right (good) and down (bad).
Is it possible to flow to the right and up?

The current version looks like:

```
[Hello World 1][Hello World 2]
[Hello World 3][Hello World 4]
```

The final version should look like:

```
[Hello World 3][Hello World 4]
[Hello World 1][Hello World 2]
```

Comment: My guess is, without updating your mark up, **No**. But I'm willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: are you trying to get all 4 lines onto one line?

Comment: That's not what it gives me... http://jsfiddle.net/wcbK9/

Comment: @Keith I'm trying implement something like tabs on a dialog window. But there is a possibility that I will have more than one row of tabs.

Comment: As long as you set the width and height parameters, floating right should keep everything in line. Just use display:inline-block; to keep it all set.

Comment: @Liam I am open to updating my mark up. Does that open up any possibilities?

Comment: If you change your mark up you can just switch 1 & 2 and 3 & 4 http://jsfiddle.net/wcbK9/1/

Comment: @Zeaklous I can't do that because the tabs are dynamically generated and I don't know ahead of time how many there will be or how wide they will be (i.e. I don't know if I will have multiple lines of tabs or not, nor will I know how many tabs will be on each line)

Comment: @JinKim then you need to wrap them in a container or use flexbox like the answers say

Comment: XY suggestion: If they're being generated dynamically, can't you control where they end up in the markup?

Comment: @AndrewClody If this is part of a responsive design, the number of columns might not be fixed (mobile might be 1 column, extra wide browsers might have 3 or 4 columns).  Adjusting the order server side would not make sense in this case.

Comment: Easy: rotate outer div 180deg; rotate inner divs 180deg. Problem solved. Simples. (see my answer for more detail ;-))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One slightly cheeky way to do this would be to rotate both the outer div and the inner divs by 180 degrees.

Rotating the outer div will mean the elements are upside-down but shown in the order you want them.

Rotating the inner divs will put them back the right way up while keeping them in the reverse order.

The whole code is as simple as this:

```
.outer, .part {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Yes, it's a very *very* cheeky hack. It's certainly not efficient in terms of processing power. And it just feels *wrong*. But you know... it works.

Here it is in action in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zW4TR/

(note: you may need vendor prefixes on the `transform` style for some browsers, and also note that it won't work in IE8 or earlier as it doesn't support transforms. (there is a way of rotating in IE8, but it it's pretty ugly and quirky, and I would worry about how well they'd work with rotations inside rotations)

Comment: this is both awful and amazing at the same time, at the moment I'm considering running out of the office screaming in both joy and despair at the same time...Love/hate it :)

Comment: @Liam -- that pretty much sums up my own reaction to it too.... "Always remember, kids: just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*."   :-)

Comment: Amazing it works! This is the outside the box thinking I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without modifying your markup, but support is extremely limited due to the fact that only 3 browsers support wrapping in Flexbox:  Opera, Chrome, IE10.

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/jvwas)

Just added a class here for simplicity:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="part">Hello World 1 </div>
    <div class="part">Hello World 2</div>
    <div class="part">Hello World 3</div>
    <div class="part">Hello World 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.part {
  -webkit-flex: 1 50%;
  -ms-flex: 1 50%;
  flex: 1 50%;
}
```

Comment: Firefox and others have partial (generally almost full) support http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: No, Firefox doesn't support wrapping (see how it is marked as *partial support*?  Read the notes for what it refers to).  IE10 is the *only* browser that's marked as having *partial support* that supports wrapping.

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvotes?  The OP does not specify browser requirements and the solution works fluidly without adjusting the markup or relying on absolute positioning.

Comment: This solution is much more universally supported on common browsers now, and seems less hacky than the double-rotation acrobatics of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I worked up. It's a bit of a messy solution - it uses absolute positioning ,:nth element, pixel-based margins, and an `!important` tag to override inline styles.

However, **there's no need to change the HTML markup at all**. This can all be achieved through a linked stylesheet.

Here's the CSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.part {
  width: inherit !important;
}

.part:nth-child(1),
.part:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.part:nth-child(3),
.part:nth-child(4){
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

.part:nth-child(4) {
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my own, and it seems that it's working correctly. Element 1 and 2 are on the upper side (tested on chrome and firefox).

**However, here are some possible solutions:**

The easiest way would be to change the order of the elements:

```
<div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 3</div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 4</div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 1 </div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 2</div>
</div>
```

But I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Another solution would be to put the divs inside another parent-div:

```
<div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 1 </div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 2</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 3</div>
     <div class="part">Hello World 4</div>
</div>
```

If you aren't able to change the HTML-Code, there might be some special CSS3-selectors wich might fit, but I cant test it, because it's already working for me.